# get a date in vb.net by know the week and day but not the date

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim x As Date
    x = "5/26/2011"
    Dim whichweek As Double = x.DayOfYear / 7
    Dim whichday As Integer = x.DayOfWeek
```

using this information could i get a certain week last year and a certain day of that week and use the date

This is return 4/10/2010 instead of 4/5/2010 and 5/26/2011 is returning 5/27/2011

```
 Public Shared Function GetWeekNumber(ByVal dtPassed As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim ciCurr As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
    Dim weekNum As Integer = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dtPassed, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
    Return weekNum
End Function

 Dim x As Date
    x = "4/04/2011"
    Dim whichweek As Integer = GetWeekNumber(x.Date)
    Dim whichday As Integer = x.DayOfWeek

    Dim offset As New TimeSpan(whichweek * 7 + whichday, 0, 0, 0)
    Dim sameWeekLastYear = New DateTime(x.Year - 1, 1, 1) + offset

    Label9.Text = sameWeekLastYear
```

Comment: As long as you compute the week like that, it is simply whichweek * 7 + whichday - 1 added to jan 1st.  Hopefully you don't compute the week like that, it's wrong.

Comment: hmm so to compute which week i should whichweek * 7 + whichday - 1 added to jan 1st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the same weekday in the same week of the previous year, you can use something like this:

```
Dim offset As New TimeSpan(whichweek * 7 + whichday, 0, 0, 0)
Dim sameWeekLastYear = New DateTime(x.Year - 1, 1, 1) + offset
```

(But as Hans said in the comments, your calculation of the week is unfortunately wrong.)

However, don’t use a string to initialise a date. In fact, your code shouldn’t even compile. You should enable `Option Strict` to make the compiler check for errors more strictly.

To initialise a date from a constant, use the date literal syntax:

```
Dim date = #5/26/2011#
```

Or, if you really *need* to read a string because you’re reading a file or getting user input, use the `DateTime.Parse` method to parse the string properly.

Comment: hmm i dont want to get the same date though, what i want is to get the same day, for example i want the monday of the 30th week of the year, the monday of the 30th week of the year may or may not be 8/20/2011 it could be a different date last year

Comment: fyi i didnt take the time to figure out what is the actual 30th week of the year lol

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Ah, that makes it more interesting. Let me think …

Comment: haha yea life would be to easy, if i just wanted the date, and a programmers life is never easy

Comment: hmm since my calculation for the week is wrong what would i ahve to change

Comment: i posted something new could u take a look